# IList<T> search help

Tags: c#

I have a `IList<Customer>` and I want to find a customer whose lastname='smith'. how do i do that? The .where looks like it might work but I don't understand the predicate needed to do this. Or is there a better way to search the list?

Thanks,
rod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the first customer which his last name is 'smith', use `FirstOrDefault`

```
var customer = customerList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.LastName == "smith");

if (customer != null)
  // do code;
```

And If you want all the customers which their last name is 'smith', use `Where`:

```
var customers = customerList.Where(c => c.LastName == "smith");

foreach(var customer in customers)
  // do code;
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Try this, assuming that your IList is the `customers` object:

```
var smiths = customers.Where(c => c.LastName == "Smith");
```

Answer (score 3):

To expand on the other posts:

Any method such as `Where()` that takes a predicate needs that predicate to return a boolean. That predicate will be evaluated against each element of the collection, and for each element where the predicate returns `true`, that element will be included in the resulting collection.

Keep in mind that `Where()` returns a collection (I believe `IEnumerable<Customer>` in your scenario, but I don't have VS open right now to verify) that you will need to get an individual element from using `First()` or `Single()` (among others). You can also use the predicate on any of the single methods such as `Single()` or `Last()` to avoid chaining `Where(x => blah).Single()`.